# How can I scale an image inside a div which is inside a grid?

Tags: html, css, web

I'm using a grid layout. I used `grid-template-column` and `grid-template-rows` to define its structure. I want the first cell to contain an image. Since I want to center it horizontally, my idea was to place it inside a div which itself can be a flex or grid container.

I'm having problems scaling the image. When not using the div, I'm basically placing the image directly inside the grid, I can use `height: 100%;` and it scales down so that the height fits the cell.

But when using an extra div container that does not work anymore. Using `height: 100%` seems to reference the height of the whole grid layout, not just the div. Google says I should use `max-height` and `max-width`, but I can't get it to work. Below is a simple test project (HTML and CSS) to show the problem. When using `width: 25px;` you can see, how big the sections of the grid should be.

I appreciate any help. Keep in mind, this is a simple test project, so don't mind the naming of my classes and IDs.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.class {
  background-color: blue;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 3fr 3fr;
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}

#image-container>img {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="class" id="image-container">
    <img src="https://www.industrialempathy.com/img/remote/ZiClJf-1920w.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="class" id="2">Good</div>
  <div class="class" id="3">Day</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the overflow on the child element class and max-height on the parent to achieve the desired result.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr repeat(2, 3fr);
  gap: 1rem;
  background: orchid;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
.class{
  background: teal;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img{
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="class">
    <img src="https://www.industrialempathy.com/img/remote/ZiClJf-1920w.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="class">
    <p>Good</p>
  </div>
  <div class="class">
    <p>Day</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My preferred method is setting it as background image, with the background-size:contain (or cover). This applies logic from the browser instead of trying to get it right yourself and is fully responsive.

```css
.exampleA, .exampleB{
    width: 34%;
    height: 150px;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: pink;  /* Just for this demo:  to display canvas size */
    border: 1px solid black; /* Just for this demo */
    display: inline-block;
}

.exampleA {
    background-size: contain;
}
.exampleB {
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="exampleA"
     style="background-image: url('https://www.industrialempathy.com/img/remote/ZiClJf-1920w.jpg');"
></div>
        
<div class="exampleB"
      style="background-image: url('https://www.industrialempathy.com/img/remote/ZiClJf-1920w.jpg');"
></div>
```

Comment: Background image really is the easiest way. Combined with the `background-size` as shown you'll get the best result.

Comment: Ah, yea. Forgot that that was an easy solution. Thanks for the help!